# How to configure `ipfw` on Lion, Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, security, firewall

I'd like to configure and start `ipfw` on Macs running `Lion`, `Mountain Lion`.

I found that `pfctl` is configured and started with:

```
/etc/pf.conf
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
```

How is `ipfw` configured and launched?

Comment: I updated my original question to clarify that I'm not talking of packet filter but ip firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guide: [Setting Up ipfw on Mac OS X](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2012/04/05/setting-up-ipfw-on-mac-os-x/), shows you how to set up IPFW on Mac OS X. The article was posted in 2012, so should apply to Lion/ML.

Comment: Well documented answer ☺.

Answer (score 2):

**ipfw is configured in `/etc/pf.conf`**

---

You can configure the ipfw using a GUI in [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/).

[image: IceFloor: Filter inbound connections]

Comment: → grgarside: thank you for the usefull info. But, `/etc/pf.conf` and `IceFloor` are for packet filter. I want to use the basic `ipfw`.